# Integral kernel of $e^{itH_{0}}$

Tags: functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

In quantum mechanics, the time-evolved state of a one-particle system is given by $\psi(x,t) = e^{-itH_{0}}\psi_{0}(x)$, where $H_{0} = \frac{1}{2}\Delta$ is the free Hamiltonian, $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\Delta$ is the usual Laplace operator. I've seen somewhere that both $e^{itH_{0}}$ and $e^{tH_{0}}$ have integral kernels, i.e.
\begin{eqnarray}
(e^{-itH_{0}}\varphi)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}K_{0}(x,y,t)\varphi_{0}(y)dy \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{eqnarray}
(e^{-tH_{0}}\varphi)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\tilde{K}_{0}(x,y,t)\varphi_{0}(y)dy \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{eqnarray}
where $K_{0}(x,y,t) = (2\pi i  t)^{-d/2}e^{i\frac{(x-y)^{2}}{2t}}$ and $\tilde{K}(x,y,t) =  (2\pi  t)^{-d/2}e^{\frac{(x-y)^{2}}{2t}}$.

**Question:** How can I prove (\ref{1}) and (\ref{2})?

Comment: Hint: Fourier transform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically we have a PDE $\partial_t \varphi(t,\vec{x}) = \alpha \, \Delta\varphi(t,\vec{x}).$

Taking the Fourier transform in the $\vec{x}$ argument results in the ODE $\partial_t \hat{\varphi}(t,\vec{k}) = -\alpha \, |\vec{k}|^2 \, \hat{\varphi}(t,\vec{k})$ with solution
$$
\hat{\varphi}(t,\vec{k}) = e^{-\alpha \, |\vec{k}|^2 t} \hat{\varphi}(0,\vec{k}).
$$

The right hand side is a product of two functions of $\vec{k}$ and is therefore the Fourier transform of a convolution:
$$
\varphi(t,\vec{x}) = \left(u(t,\cdot)*\varphi(0,\cdot)\right)(\vec{x}),
$$
where $\hat{u}(t,\vec{k}) = e^{-\alpha \, |\vec{k}|^2 t}.$

If $\operatorname{Re}\alpha \geq 0$ then $\hat{u}$ can be transformed resulting in
$$
u(t,\vec{x}) = (2\pi\alpha t)^{-d/2}e^{-\frac{|\vec{x}|^{2}}{2\alpha t}}.
$$

Thus,
$$
\varphi(t,\vec{x}) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} (2\pi\alpha t)^{-d/2}e^{-\frac{|\vec{x}-\vec{y}|^{2}}{2\alpha t}} \, \varphi(0,\vec{y}) \, d^dy.
$$